# Create Chat room with XMPPFramework openfire

Tags: objective-c, xmppframework, ios8.1, chatroom

I'm working on a chat App where I have to add group chat
functionality using `XMPP Framework` . I'm able to setup
`peer-to-peer` chatting. But when it comes to group chat ,I'm unable
to create a `chat room`. I know, this question has been asked many
times before, but I could not find any solution from that answers.
Here's my code for creating and configuring a chat room.

```
- (void)createChatRoom:(NSString *) newRoomName
{
    NSString *jid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",newRoomName,kGroupChatDomain];
    XMPPRoomMemoryStorage * _roomMemory = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc]init];
    XMPPJID * roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:jid];
    _xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:_roomMemory
                                                           jid:roomJID
                                                 dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSString *nickName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@chatRoom",newRoomName];
    [_xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:nickName
                            history:nil
                           password:nil];
    [_xmppRoom activate:[AppDel xmppStream]];
    [_xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
}

- (void)xmppRoomDidCreate:(XMPPRoom *)sender{
    NSLog(@"didCreateChat Room method called");
}

- (void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender{
    NSLog(@"xmppRoomDidJoin method called ");
}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchConfigurationForm:(NSXMLElement *)configForm{
    NSXMLElement *newConfig = [configForm copy];
    NSArray* fields = [newConfig elementsForName:@"field"];
    for (NSXMLElement *field in fields) {
        NSString *var = [field attributeStringValueForName:@"var"];
        if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_persistentroom"]) {
            [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
            [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];
        }
    }
    [sender configureRoomUsingOptions:newConfig];
}
```

Above is the code to create and configure the chat room. Before
calling this code, I'm connecting `XMPP` in `viewDidLoad` method. But
I'm unable to create a chat room. Code is not calling `XMPPRoom`
`Delegate` methods `(xmppRoomDidCreate, xmppRoomDidJoin)` I don't know
where I'm doing wrong, please correct me if there's any mistake in my
code. I could not even find any error in openfire logs. Please help me
resolving the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create room and if room already created you can easily join existing group using this code

```
- (void)createOrEnterRoom:(NSString *)groupName
{
    BOOL flag=valueExistInGroup(groupName);
    if (flag==TRUE) {
        savevalueInGroup(groupName);

        XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];
        XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@conference.your_server_name",groupName]];
        XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomStorage
                                                               jid:roomJID
                                                     dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

        [xmppRoom activate:xmppStream];
        [xmppRoom addDelegate:self
                delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:xmppStream.myJID.user
                                history:nil
                               password:nil];
 }
    else
    {
        NSString *strJid=[AppSetting getUserId];
        strJid=[strJid stringByAppendingFormat:@"@your_server_name"];
        _xmppRoomStorage = [XMPPRoomHybridStorage sharedInstance];
        XMPPJID *roomJid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@conference.52.10.97.23",groupName]];
        XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:_xmppRoomStorage jid:roomJid];
        [xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        [xmppRoom activate:xmppStream];
        NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
        [history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:@"10"];
        [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:strJid history:nil];
    }
}


- (void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender{
    [sender fetchConfigurationForm];
}

- (void)fetchConfigurationForm
{
    dispatch_block_t block = ^{ @autoreleasepool {

        XMPPLogTrace();

        // <iq type='get'
        //       id='config1'
        //       to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'>
        //   <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner'/>
        // </iq>

        NSString *fetchID = [xmppStream generateUUID];

        NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:XMPPMUCOwnerNamespace];
        XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get" to:roomJID elementID:fetchID child:query];

        [xmppStream sendElement:iq];

        [responseTracker addID:fetchID
                        target:self
                      selector:@selector(handleConfigurationFormResponse:withInfo:)
                       timeout:60.0];

    }};

    if (dispatch_get_specific(moduleQueueTag))
        block();
    else
        dispatch_async(moduleQueue, block);
}
```

Comment: if you face any problem let me know

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @suthar, Actually I am able to create chat room and adding users as member to the chat room. But I am stuck at coreData integration. How to save and retrieve chat room list and messages from coreData provided by XMPPFramework ?

Comment: Currently i'm using sqlite for this , you can also use sqlite for save chat

Comment: Can't we do it with coreData ? Because XMPPFramework provides datamodels for it.

Comment: Yes i know that but i didn't worked on coreData , thats why i choose sqlite for this

Comment: I am getting multiple messages when I join already created room, can anyone help why it happens ?

Comment: NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
        [history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:@"0"];